# Sort dates using groupby pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which contains dates in the format: yyyy-mm-dd:

```
id1 = ['2015-09-23', '2014-07-08', '2015-07-30', '2008-09-26',
       '2009-07-13', '2009-09-28', '2014-04-10', '2009-06-03']

id2 = ['2011-04-15', '2015-11-30', '2015-06-15', '2015-12-01',
       '2015-12-23', '2009-01-14', '2009-06-17', '2009-08-07']

id3 = ['2010-01-26', '2010-03-16', '2011-11-23', '2012-01-31',
       '2012-06-08', '2012-10-26', '2013-01-07', '2013-11-12']

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':id1 + id2 + id3,'id':['id1']*8+['id2']*8+['id3']*8})
```

[image]

From this, I want to get the first and last date for each id.

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby(['id'])['dates'].agg({'sort':sorted})
```

[image]

The problem with that is that I'm only able to see the first date not the last. I'll like to have as output a list with only two elements: first and last date. Instead of the whole list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

easy peasy

```
df.groupby('id').dates.agg({'date ': ['first', 'last']})
```

Comment: Interesting, but it seems it's taking the order of the elements in the list rather  than sorting by date. I want to know with are the earlier and last dates

Comment: then replace first and last by min and max. you can accept my solution then haha

Comment: Where are this first,last  functions defined? pandas?

Comment: look at the documentation online

Answer (score 4):

```
In[8]: df.groupby(['id']).dates.apply(lambda x: [min(x),max(x)])
Out[8]: 
id
id1    [2008-09-26, 2015-09-23]
id2    [2009-01-14, 2015-12-23]
id3    [2010-01-26, 2013-11-12]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in first and last

```
df.groupby(['id'])['dates'].agg(['first', 'last'])
```

That gives you

```
    first       last
id      
id1 2015-09-23  2009-06-03
id2 2011-04-15  2009-08-07
id3 2010-01-26  2013-11-12
```

Comment: are you kidding me? this is my solution

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: [sorted(x['dates'])[0],
                                    sorted(x['dates'])[-1]])
```

This requires **sorting twice**, so you might want to define the lambda as a helper function.

Answer (score 2):

I picked up from where you left, and here is your solution with just two lines and list comprehension:

```
>>> new_df = df.groupby(['id'])['dates'].agg({'sort':sorted})
>>> new_df
                                                  sort
id
id1  [2008-09-26, 2009-06-03, 2009-07-13, 2009-09-2...
id2  [2009-01-14, 2009-06-17, 2009-08-07, 2011-04-1...
id3  [2010-01-26, 2010-03-16, 2011-11-23, 2012-01-3...
>>> new_df['sort'] = [[lst[0], lst[-1]] for lst in new_df['sort'].tolist()]
>>> new_df
                         sort
id
id1  [2008-09-26, 2015-09-23]
id2  [2009-01-14, 2015-12-23]
id3  [2010-01-26, 2013-11-12]
>>>
```